# Outlook structure

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Are all emails, todos, calander items held in one file for Microsoft Outlook (I.e the OST and PST file)? If so why do they use the one file?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As James noted, they're all in one file by default. I expect the reason is based on a number of factors, least of all that it's easier to back up one file, it locks you in to Outlook, and it has features including compressible encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook indexes all items for searchability, I guess it's much easier to index a database than a file structure. Plus all the reasons mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't set it up to split it, yes they are all in said file.